# Looping an algorithm for three entities

Tags: ruby, loops

I am facing problems generating a loop in Ruby that is to be pushed to a GAMS include file. It should display each tuple of a c(i,j) vector, for all i and j, i. e.

```
Parameter c(i,j) /
c('i1','j1')=[value];
c('i1','j2')=[value];
.
.
.
c('iI','jJ')=[value];
/
```

The problem is, that there are three entities to fetch data from, so that I struggle to identify the respective distance between warehouses and clients. This is the loop so far:

```
printf(f, "Parameter c(i,j) / \n")
@warehouses.each { |wh| printf(f, "c('i" + wh.id.to_s + "',") +
@clients.each { |cl| printf(f, "'j" + cl.id.to_s + "')=") +
@transquans.distance.to_s(@warehouses, @clients) + "; \n"
}
}
```

The structure behind that is uploaded [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45905590/datastructure.png).

The error message returned is like this: "undefined method `distance' for nil:NilClass".

Comment: It means that `@transquans` is `nil` for one of the loops. Where and how do you set it ?

Comment: I created the models via scaffolding without too many manual changes. Transquans can be set manually by the user in the application with integer values for distance and quan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved by now!

```
printf(f, "Parameter c(i,j) / \n")
@warehouses.each do |wh|
  @clients.each do |cl|
    transquan = Transquan.where(:warehouse_id => wh.id, :client_id => cl.id).first
    if transquan.nil?
    else
      printf(f, "c('i" + wh.id.to_s + "' , 'j" + cl.id.to_s + "')=" + transquan.distance.to_s + ";\n")
    end
  end
end
```